# Resolve Navigation Error in React Native : Initial Route Name is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

I am getting this warning and even though the initialRouteName is set to MountedScreen still it open unmountedScreen at start.
Also anywhere I am pressing TouchableOpacity, the screen navigates to next screen.

Warning: Cannot update a component (`ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer)`) while rendering a different component (`StateChangeScreen`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `StateChangeScreen`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render

```
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import React from 'react';

import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import MountedScreen from './screens/mounted';
import StateChangeScreen from './screens/stateChange';
import UnmountedScreen from './screens/unMounted';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Mounted">
        <Stack.Screen name="Mounted" component={MountedScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="StateChange" component={StateChangeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Unmounted" component={UnmountedScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```